97-keys piano in Finale
How can I obtain a 97-keys piano in Finale26 MakeMusic?
I'm using the Steinway D Concert Grand Piano: for GPO5. On this site I found the instructions to solve my problem, but I haven't managed to find the <region> tag and thus how to adjust the lokey and hikey values.
Please, could someone help me?

You need to edit the Steinway Concert D.sfz file. This has several region groups for different velocities (both for no pedal and sustain), so you're looking for several regions to edit.
But the principle of extending the key value to a range of hikey, lokey and a pitch_keycenter still applies.
